# Gridview Columns to Excel

Tags: export

I'm using GridView to show data. And for exporting Gridview data into excel format, 
I'm using a button - "Export to Excel". The downloading into Excel format or 
Exporting into Excel is working perfectly. That GridView is showing total of 15 Columns.

But in the excel document its showing only 14 columns. What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code so we could have a look ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this coding

In Button click

```
           Response.Clear();
           Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
           Response.Charset = "";
           Page.EnableViewState = false;
           Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=report.xls");
           System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
           System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
           GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
           Response.Write(tw.ToString());
           Response.End();
```

and add the event

```
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
```

I hope the following link will help you

[Export-GridView-to-Excel-without-losing-gridlines-in-Excel-file-in-ASPNet](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-without-losing-gridlines-in-Excel-file-in-ASPNet.aspx)

[Solution-ASPNet-GridView-Export-to-Excel-The-file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in-a-different-format-than-specified-by-the-file-extension](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Solution-ASPNet-GridView-Export-to-Excel-The-file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in-a-different-format-than-specified-by-the-file-extension.aspx)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.